# How to implement a custom pooling layer in tensorflow using existing tensorflow python API

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to implement a custom pooling layer which takes a bounding box around the maximum value in each channel of feature map.

I have implemented this in numpy like the following:

```
def pooling_np(input):
#input:[batch,h,v,channel]
#output:[batch,h/2,v/2,channel]
pooling = np.empty([input.shape[0], input.shape[1]/2, input.shape[2]/2, input.shape[3]])
for i_batch in range(input.shape[0]):
    for j_channel in range(input.shape[-1]):
        max_id = np.argmax(input[i_batch,:,:,j_channel])
        #[i_batch,max_h,max_v,j_channel]
        max_h = max_id / input.shape[1]
        max_v = max_id % input.shape[1]
        #begin point:(left,up)
        left = max(min(max_h, input.shape[1]/2), 0)
        up = max(min(max_v, input.shape[2]/2), 0)
        pooling[i_batch,:,:,j_channel] = input[i_batch,left:left+input.shape[1]/2,up:up+input.shape[2]/2,j_channel]
return pooling
```

As [Adding a New Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) says, I am trying to implement this using a composition of existing operations. But I find tensorflow python API is not that fancy like numpy, I tried this but it is extremely inefficient(10s for one batch image) and didn't give me the same result.

```
def pooling(input, name='pooling'):
"""Downsampling operation.
:param value: A Tensor of shape [b, d0, d1, ch]
:return: A Tensor of shape [b, d0/2, d1/2, ch]
"""
with tf.name_scope(name) as scope:
    #input_dim: [batch_size, width, height, depth]
    input_dim = input.get_shape().as_list()
    output = tf.Variable(tf.cast(tf.zeros([input_dim[0],input_dim[1]/2, input_dim[2]/2, input_dim[3]]), tf.float32))
    for i_batch in range(input_dim[0]):
        for j_depth in range(input_dim[-1]):
            #in_slice: 
            in_slice = tf.slice(input,[i_batch,0,0,j_depth], [1,input_dim[1], input_dim[2],1])
            in_slice_reshape_1d = tf.reshape(in_slice, [input_dim[1] * input_dim[2]])
            in_slice_reshape_3d = tf.reshape(in_slice, [input_dim[1] , input_dim[2], 1])
            max_id = tf.argmax(in_slice_reshape_1d, axis = 0)
            i_horizontal = tf.floordiv(max_id, input_dim[1])
            j_vertical = tf.floormod(max_id, input_dim[1])
            left = tf.maximum(tf.subtract(i_horizontal, tf.cast(tf.floordiv(input_dim[1], 2), tf.int64)), 0)
            left = tf.minimum(left, input_dim[1])
            up = tf.maximum(tf.subtract(j_vertical, tf.cast(tf.floordiv(input_dim[2], 2), tf.int64)), 0)
            up = tf.minimum(up, input_dim[2])
            slice_output = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(tf.cast(in_slice_reshape_3d, tf.int32),tf.cast(up, tf.int32), tf.cast(left, tf.int32), input_dim[1]/2, input_dim[2]/2)
            slice_output = tf.cast(slice_output, tf.float32)
            output[i_batch,:,:,j_depth].assign(slice_output)
        print(str(i_batch)+' finished') 
    return output
```

Is there any easier way to implement this custom pooling layer?

Comment: You can try [tf.py_funct](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/script_ops/script_language_operators_#py_func) for your numpy function. AFAIK implementing a decent custom pooling layer in tensorflow would require you to implement in C++ and [do a lot of work](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op).

Comment: @umutto, I'm curious, would we need to also implement the custom gradient op for this layer (since this is a composition of existing ops)?